# Get the full word by few letters, API?

Tags: algorithm, api, crossword

I have a problem: for example, we have a few letters: `b,o,s`. It's a letters from some word and they go in the same order as in word (in this case word is `books`). But, of course, it may be another word.

So I need to get the list of the possible words, for example, lenght = 10. How can I do these? I feel, that the problem is close to crossword solving, so may be there is some services with API?

Comment: what have you done so far. do you have any code to share

Answer (score 0):

- Get yourself a word list https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=english+word+list
- Put the words in a database table CREATE TABLE Words(Word VARCHAR(64) PRIMARY KEY) ... INSERT INTO Words(Word) VALUE(UPPER(@word)) ...
- Query the table with a LIKE query SELECT Word FROM Words WHERE Word LIKE 'B%O%S'